# Determine if a user has family sharing enabled

Tags: ios, icloud, apple-id

Is there a way to determine if a user has family sharing enabled or an Apple-ID set on their device? I don't need to know details about the apple-id, just to now if I need to guide the user towards setting it up.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no API to determine whether a user has family sharing enabled.
There is only an option to distinguish between a purchaser and family members after the purchase is complete.
That info is stored in the user's receipt under the [in_app_ownership_type field](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/in_app_ownership_type).

Comment: do you know then if there is a way to determine if an Apple-ID user is a child or a regular adult account?